# Can't add google Dns confirmation Txt Record to godaddy's name server

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers, google-search-console

I am trying to verify my website on google console and it is asking me to add the verification code into dns configurations. I purchased the domain from godaddy and hosting my website on aws server that's why godaddy's dns configuration has name servers provided by aws.

Now when I am trying edit the records of my domain in Godaddy.

It says:
We can't display your DNS information because your nameservers aren't managed by us.

Which is because I am not using Godaddy's nameservers.

I wanted to know which is the right place to add the googe verifcation code is it godaddy or aws?

If it is AWS where should I add the record.

Comment: It is in AWS, in Route53, in your hosted zone.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers help them following this. By voting question and answer both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open AWS Route53
2. Create Hosted Zone if you are not created.
3. If already created then create record set
4. Select TXT record and add your value.

[image]